# Is there any web app that will rotate ads on my website?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any web app that will allow me to easily maintain ads on my website?

On a website I manage I sell ads and currently paste them into place by hand.

Is there an app that would allow me to easily manage these ads?

<sub>Something that could monitor clicks and rotate ads would be great.</sub>

Comment: seems like a question for webmasterspro for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Google AdManager.

http://www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/

> Google Ad Manager offers a wealth of inventory management, ad targeting, trafficking, and other features

Comment: The URL returns 404

Comment: I've updated the link

Comment: dfp is a great service form google

Answer (score 0):

Google AdManager has been replaced with "DFP Small Business". Free up to 90 million ad impressions per month.

http://www.google.com/dfp/info/sb/

I've been testing the product for a few weeks and it seems to do just about everything I need, including handling ad code from 3rd party ad servers.

For me the only missing feature is the ability to serve ads in emails.